# MySQL Populating field if data exists in another table

Tags: mysql, select, join

This is well and truly beyond my skillset and I can't seem to figure out how to link this data:

I have a 3 tables with information about ongoing jobs.

- Header - Stores customer info and last updated
- Data - All the data from the report
- Notes - Notes added against a row

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/822672/1

What I want is all the data for Customer with id=2 and I just want the last column to have a value (any value) if any Notes exist

e.g.

where Data.key_name=RO No 
and 
Data.key_value=Notes.ro_number

Comment: in your example, the notes only have ro number 210214 which doesn't exist in your Data, so you want the last column to display nothing for all the row? i still don't understand the expected result for this scenario

Comment: All rows should be shown with the final column blank if there is no match

Comment: All you have to do is change the `LEFT JOIN` condition to be what you wrote in your last sentence. [Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/822672/12)

Comment: So simple... yet I was so lost...